# CakePHP - passing multiple values from a view element to the controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to pass some values to my controller from the view.

Actually I'm using the following code:

```php
 <?
echo $this->element('produtos-categoria', array(
    'categoria_id' => $produtos['Produto']['categoriasproduto_id'],
    'produto_id' => $produtos['Produto']['id']
));
?>
```

But I'm not able to get the second value in my controller, just the first value is coming:

```php
public function list_categories($categoria_id = null, $produto_id = null ) {
        pr($produto_id); exit; //empty
    }
```

Anyone can help how to get the second value?

Comment: try like `public function listacategorias((Array)$category_data) {
        pr($category_data); exit;`

Comment: check this and tell what is printed out?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL generated by `findBySlug()`? It is not clear what the Element has to do with your problem. It sounds like your issue is purely to do with the retrieval of data in your Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I donno what are you trying to achieve but to get  the second variable you would need to set the second parameter to your method.

```
// If you want to set variable from a function and get it from an other function
public function an_other_function(){
    $this->listacategorias(22, 333);
}

public function listacategorias($categoria_id = null, $produto_id = null ) {
    var_dump($categoria_id);
    var_dump($produto_id);
}


// If you want to set and get variable from url
host_or_domain_name/controller_name/listacategorias/22/33
```